# Python 3 Framework for automated trading

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite, algorithmic-trading

Currently, I work on a day trading project for my own but I don't know where to start when it comes to the use of Database.

Goal: create a trading bot. (I already have the algorithm)

Issue: I need help on the process and the tool to use.

Currently, I've got a programme that runs 24h/24 and extracts live financial data.

1. I think this programme output should be inserted into a SQL database because there will be millions of rows.
   Is this correct assumption?
2. Then I need to perform a live calculation to add my algorithm output on a new column of this database.
   Is this correct assumption or should I have a separate database for live calculation linked with my algorithm?

I'm getting lost about the framework and tool  I should use as best practice whether it is parallel computing, SQL/NoSQL database, PySpark and so on.

Comment: with `pandas` is easy to works with data and you can find tutorials how to use `pandas` in trading with "time series". Some people use `pandas` even with big files - few GB. I think there is even module to use `pandas` with `pyspark` But if it will not works then I would use database. You have modules `SQLAlchemy`, `peewee` to work with different databases - Postgres, MySQL, (eventually SQLite). You will have always the same columns so you don't need NoSQL.

Comment: @furas thanks for the answer. Is pandas considered as good practice for these type of work? Does using database allow me to skip PySpark or do I have to use it anyway to gain efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first assumption:
Assuming you're going to have millions of rows inserted in to a single table without any correlations/constraints being done or needed I'd suggest reading about NoSQL (e.g MongoDB) which when assuming this assumption could also give the proper solution for your second question.

I'd suggest reading: http://www.automatedtrader.net/articles/technology-strategy/157883/python-for-analysing-financial-markets

Good luck!